# ViewController tableview won't update after load

Tags: uitableview, ios6, uinavigationcontroller

I am new to iOS development.In my app i want to update some value in current ViewController's tableview  while coming back from the NextViewController.i reload the tableview in current view controller's viewDidAppear method but it dosen't work.i am using Navigationcontroller.Please help me if anyone know.

Comment: Please, add some code.

Comment: add your code in viewWillApper. update the value and reload the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Add your code in `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`
You could also use [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) based on what you are trying to do